# Plot functions in R with coordinate axis and arrows

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I'm a relative beginner in *R* so please forgive me if it's a noob question.

So, is there a package which provides an easy interface to plot (real-real, mathematical) functions? I need coordinate axis with arrows (and their intersection should be *(0;0)*) and ticks, grid, etc. I want similar plots as in [this document](http://uzsolt.hu/static/stuff/math/exams/09/fuggveny_elemzes.pdf).

Background: now I create function plots with LaTeX's *tikzpicture* and *axis* but I'm using *R* to generate randomized exams since few months (*R* creates *tex*-files and include them into document) and would be nice if *R* can create similar plots (png, jpg), because *axis* in LaTeX is very slow.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't know a package at the moment, but you easily could do this with `arrows`, `points`, and `abline`.

Comment: Could you provide a simple example? (In a normal answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With R graphic tools such as `arrows`, `points`, `abline`, etc. you can draw practically anything.

### Example

```
op <- par(mar=c(1, 1, 1, 1))  ## adjust outer margins
plot(x, y, type="n", axes=F, asp=1, xlab="", ylab="")  ## asp=1 to maintain 1:1 aspect ratio
lines(x, y, lwd=2)
arrows(par()$usr[1], 0, par()$usr[2], length=.05)  ## par()$usr helps to find xlim and ylim
arrows(0, par()$usr[3], 0, par()$usr[4], length=.05)
points((-5:5)*10, rep(0, 11), pch=3, cex=.6)  ## pch=3 for crosses
points(rep(0, 11), (-5:5)*10, pch=3, cex=.6)
mtext("y", 3, -1, adj=.55, font=8)
mtext("x", 4, -1, padj=-1, las=2, font=8)
abline(h=(-5:5)*10, lty=3, col="gray")
abline(v=(-5:5)*10, lty=3, col="gray")
text(10, -4, "10", font=7, cex=.8)
text(-4, 10, "10", font=7, cex=.8)
par(op)  ## reset par
```

[image]

---

*Data*

```
x <- (-10):10; y <- x^2 - 50
```

Comment: It's impressive too. I'll investigate it too. Thanks! (Why can't accept two answers?)

Answer (score 3):

I made you a little function for this

```
math_plot <- function(f, xlim = c(-2,2), ylim = c(-2,2), 
                      xlab = "x", ylab = "f(x)", ax.ext = .02,
                      frame.plot = F, grid.tick = .1, ...){

  curve(f, from = xlim[1], to = xlim[2], ylim = ylim, 
                      axes = F, xlab = "", ylab = "",
                      frame.plot = frame.plot, ...)

  # x-axis
  axis(1, pos = 0)
  arrows(x0 = xlim[2], x1 = xlim[2] + diff(xlim)*ax.ext, y0 = 0, length = .1)
  mtext(text = xlab, side = 4, line = 0, las = 2, at = 0)

  # y-axis
  axis(2, pos = 0, las = 2)
  arrows(y0 = ylim[2], y1 = ylim[2] + diff(ylim)*ax.ext, x0 = 0, length = .1)
  mtext(text = ylab, side = 3, line = 0, at = 0)

  grid(nx = diff(xlim)/grid.tick, ny = diff(ylim)/grid.tick)
}

# give it a function
math_plot(function(x) 3*x + 2 - 2*x^2, ylim = c(-2,4))
```

[image]

Comment: Missed feature: arrows :) And is it possible to place label `x` to near the x-axis (as in the linked document) - and the `y` too?

Comment: @uzsolt Ah, yes. Give me a minute

Comment: @uzsolt Done. The labels follow the axes, at position 0, so they may end up outside the plotting region if 0 is not in it.

Comment: it's very impressive, thanks! I'll understand and modify when I need something. Thanks!